# How to auto fill data only (not format)

Tags: excel, vba

In Cell B6 there is number 1 and its color is red. but other cells are not red and there is no any data in them. after executing the following code, from B6 to B18, will be filled with numbers 1 ~ 13 but here there is a problem! i don't want to copy red color of B6 to B7 ... B8 ... B9 ... and ... i just need to copy without format of the base cell...

```
    Range("B6").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("B6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B6:B18"),Type:=xlFillSeries
```

Can i find something like this property: xlFillSeriesWithoutFormat or a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>According to the [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838605%28v=office.14%29.aspx)*, it seems that `xlFillValues` would be your best bet:</strike>

> Copy only the values from the source range to the target range, repeating if necessary.

All the other options explicitly state that they will copy formatting. It looks like your only options are:

- remove the formatting from the destination cells after copying
- not have formatting to copy by:

  1. save off the formatting
  2. remove the formatting from the source cell
  3. do the `.AutoFill`
  4. then restore the formatting to the source cell

<sup>*found by a Google search for "excel vba .autofill"</sup>

Comment: but unfortunately the xlFillValues property just copied the number 1 (that was in the B6) to all other cells!!! anyway tnx for your time :(

Comment: actually i was searching for a low level way (fast way) like xlFillSeries that officially registered in excel... so, it seems that this low speed way is the only way. anyway tnx for the time :(